# Programming and computer science basics

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, computer-science

Today, to make MySQL work on my Ubuntu i found some piece of code that i had to type in the terminal to install MySQL server. Then i had to insert some code like:

```
mysql -u root -p   /*enter*/
```

then insert my password and enter again.
At this point i created a new database with the code

```
mysql> create database MyFirstDatabase;   /*enter*/
```

Fact is that i have no idea of what i did and why. Why did i have to install MySQL server and why my workbench wasn't working before? Why my username was root?
Where the database file was created, in which folder?

I want to be able to know the answer to questions like:"what happen in the machine when i declare a variable?" or "What happen if i declare an array with a certain number of elements but with no content in them?" and also "what happens in the pc when i run a SQL query with an inner join?".

***ADDITIONS***
I had also no idea why one of the IT technician of the university asked me if i had an apache server. Why did he ask this? I admit i have no idea of client/server from a technical perspective

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend a book, tutorial, tool, library, or other off-site resource are off-topic here. Google and Bing are both excellent ways to search for information and get links to the results of that search, and Amazon and other companies sell tons of computer books. Amazon will even allow you to order the search results by review ratings. This site is for specific **programming** (code) and programmers tools related questions, not for computer knowledge tutorials or lessons. Good luck.

Comment: I have difficulty seeing how someone in a masters program would have this many questions on such basic items.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are looking for a recommendation for an introductory text on computer science.  I suggest (really) that you ask your tutors at college!  People on stackoverflow are either like me (introductory text was read over 30 years ago) or much younger (was read last week and they only read one)

Comment: I have some doubts about the actual point of this question. I personally think it's *only* about the MySQL issue here..

Comment: Also, if he's used Oracle, how does he not understand the creation of DB's?

Comment: Submitted an *heavily edited* edit, however ***this question is still off-topic***.

Comment: I am sorry but i wasn't joking. It is just that i never had a proper introduction to CS. Beside, i am glad that in the UK CS is a taught subject in schools, but where i am from we were glad to have a pc in the whole school; hence i never had a formal introduction to it. I am sorry i bothered you and thanks anyway for the answers!

Comment: @Pezze So you understand about computer architecture, binary, etc, but don't know how to install and operate a command-line program? As to `Why did i have to install MySQL server`: *MySQL Workbench is a **management** program for MySQL servers, MySQL Server is the actual MySQL server*.

Comment: Sorry about the close. I think I understand how you are feeling though. There's A LOT that goes on behind the scenes when you fire up MySQL or when you are doing high-level programming.

It's easy to feel overwhelmed but try to focus on the problem you are currently solving. Figure out what you need to know to solve it, but keep an open mind. Look for patterns, form theories and perform small experiments to see if your theory holds up.

Stay curious, and with time you will understand more and more. Eventually you will see that you have a pretty good understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: @andré Laszlo. I probably explained my problem really badly. For instance i know that when you declare a variable the processor is going to allocate a certain space on the ram equal to the space required by the primitive type. What happen when i declare an integer array of 150 elements with value assigned? How heavy is an if statement from a processor perspective? -> if i am working on an algorithm with a loop to discover prime numbers, how much lighter is it going to be if i am able to take away an if statement? I have a basic understanding of this in coding, but no idea in DBs.

Comment: @Pezze, you can think of the database as a complex data structure, that has a number of properties that are nice for a programmer. If a part of your algorithm can benefit from any of these properties (ACID, relations, indexing, ...) then go for it. Think of the DB as a [black box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box) initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inserting the first command in the terminal you're accessing the MySQL cli interface which commands the MySQL server. The second command (with prompt mysql>) is a query itself made directly in the cli and submitted at your enter.

For what MySQL is used for... well you should already know, as "Oracle", it is a relational database and it is used to store data in a relational way.

Root is the username with ALL privileges, in every field, the root user is the one who have all the power in his hand. Database files are usually stored in /var/lib/mysql if I remember correctly (on Ubuntu).

For the other questions I can't really answer you since it would require much time and starting from scratch.

**Beware:** Asking for suggestions or recommendations in this site is a good way to get your question closed.